# android - Помогите с выбором виджета

Tags: android

Нужно реализовать навигацию между 5 экранами в приложении путем нажатий на кнопки внизу экрана. Нужно будет сделать анимации переходов, помечать нажатую кнопку выбранной. И чтобы нельзя было нажимать на кнопку, открывающую уже открытый экран. Я не знаю, что лучше использовать: вкладки, радиокнопки или что?  Контента много, очень много. Нужен мощный виджет, способный это переварить. Viewflipper не справляется, глючат анимации.И приложение жестко тормозит при навигации по кнопкам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, вам подойдёт ViewPager (вместе с PagerAdapter). Вот, например, неплохой урок по созданию такого элемента - http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html.

Comment: спасибо :) это то, что мне нужно